# Handling multiple chackbox state in a bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of checkbox shown in a bottomsheet.

The checkbox state is updated but it's not getting checked.

That is the list is shown, but when I check the checkbox, nothing happens... but log shows the state is updated to true.

```
BlocBuilder<PaymentApprovalCubit, SettingsFetchState>(
                

builder: (context, membersState){
                      if(membersState is SettingsFetchLoaded){
                        List<bool> _checkedState = List.filled(membersState.data.length, false);
                        return ClickableFormField(
                          hintText: "Select an option",
                          onPressed: () async {
                            final TeamMembersResponse? result =
                            await FutureBottomSheetStateful<TeamMembersResponse>(
                              future: () => Future.value(membersState.data),
                              itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                                return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 14,
                                      horizontal: 8,
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Checkbox(
                                          checkColor: AppColors.passBlack,
                                          activeColor: AppColors.passBlack.withOpacity(0.1),
                                          value: _checkedState[index],
                                          onChanged: (value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _checkedState[index] = value!;
                                              Log.e("chs", _checkedState[index]);
                                             },
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}",
                                              style: context.textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(fontSize: 14).bold,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              item.email??"",
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: AppColors.greySubTitle,
                                                  fontSize: 12
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    )
                                );
                              },
                            ).show(context);
                            setState(() {
                              if (result != null) {
                                /*requestDto = requestDto.copyWith(
                                      businessCategory: result.businessId,
                                      businessDesc: result.categoryName,
                                    );*/
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      }
                      return const SizedBox.shrink();
                    },
   ),
```

**FutureBottomSheet**

```
class FutureBottomSheetStateful<T> extends StatefulWidget with BaseBottomSheetMixin {
const FutureBottomSheetStateful(
  {required this.future,
  required this.itemBuilder,
  this.title = "",
  this.onItemSelected,
  Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final Future<List<T>> Function() future;
  final Function(T)? onItemSelected;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T item, int index) itemBuilder;

  @override
  State<FutureBottomSheetStateful<T>> createState() => 
_FutureBottomSheetStatefulState<T>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => this;

}

class _FutureBottomSheetStatefulState<T> extends State<FutureBottomSheetStateful<T>> 
{

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 var child = FutureBuilder<List<T>>(
    future: widget.future(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var item = snapshot.data![index];
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (widget.onItemSelected != null) {
                    widget.onItemSelected!(item);
                  } else {
                    context.pop(item);
                  }
                },
                child: widget.itemBuilder(context, item, index),
              );
            });
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const PassErrorWidget();
      }
      return const PassLoadingWidget();
    });

    return BaseBottomSheet(title: widget.title, child: child);
  }
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong? It seems the setState not working

Comment: Use statementManagement approach to inject values directly inside bottomsheet widget than rather passing value from constructor, becaseu ur bottomsheet is created with the initial value from constructor and will remain same no matter u change value, so either maintain the value within bottomsheet or use stateManagement for notifying changes

Comment: please can you help with example?? thanks